# Error al generar apk React-Native

Tags: react-native

Buenas noches recien acabo de terminar mi apk en react-native, pero al general el buid final para distribuirla me genera el siguiente error:

este comando use para generar el apk:

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema, y a pesar de que agregué "android.enableAapt2=false", el problema persiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiene simple solución, abre con Android Studio tu carpeta android.

Localiza el archivo gradle.properties y añade la siguiente línea:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Haz clean y vuelve a ejecutar el comando:

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```